# Rails manifest assets is undefined or not an object, while AJAX request in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get the file names of some files via ajax (to get them via ajax later) out of the Manifest.json file, since our filenames are digested. To do so I am using the following bit of code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: assetUrl + '/manifest.json',
    async: false,
    success: function(xhr){
        for(var polyfill in polyfills){
            if(polyfills.hasOwnProperty(polyfill)){
                polyfills[polyfill] = xhr['assets'][polyfill];
                //also tried:
                //polyfills[polyfill] = xhr.assets[polyfill];
            };
        };
    },
    error: function(e){
    }
});
```

When I run the script from my localhost in runs fine in IE8, but as soon as I run the script on the development server, I am getting the error that assets is null or not an object, even though it exists on the server and has the exact same structure as the file on my localhost. IE8 runs in standard mode in both cases.

Any idea what could be behind that? Or is there a better approach to get a file via ajax from the prcompiled assets? I don't want to copy them to the folder public-folder every time.

EDIT:

The development server runs with a slightly different configuration as the localhost (e.g. files get precompiled, which is why I have to go over the manifest.json).

The contents of the manifest.json look like so:

```
{
"files":{
   "file1-734fcaba023083e43850b25addddd642.eot":{
      "logical_path":"file1.eot",
      "mtime":"2015-07-30T08:26:32+00:00",
      "size":2812,
      "digest":"734fcaba023083e43850b25addddd642"
     },
     ....
}
"assets":{
          "file1":"file1-ea625da9302d183ca2b0c75e61ba88d9.eot",
          ....
}
}
```

Comment: can you show what data is coming in `xhr`?

Comment: Also can you clarify what you mean development server? And is your development server responding with the exact same xhr as it was in localhost?

Comment: Thanks for your hints, see the update above. And yes, both servers are returning the same xhr. Running the returned json through a linter, returns valid. So the JSON should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, turned out the development server uses https:// which apparently makes a huge difference when using jQuery.ajax(), using jQuery.getJSON() worked instead.